# xlib push window to the back of the other windows

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm working on making with first application using c and xlib, so far it's going great and doing what I want! It's a borderless window that is automatically fullscreened when the app is launched.

My application is going to be have some utilities like a clock and current weather that sit on the desktop.

So to do this, I need to be able to push my window to the back of all the other windows, and keep it there.

My question is, how can I push the window to behind all the other open windows (and ideally behind cairo-dock, but not required), and keep it there?

Comment: What if there are *two* programs that want to push their respective windows to the back of all the other windows *and keep them there*? Fight! Having said that, you may want to try calling XLowerWindow in the beginning and every time you get  an event selected by StructureNotifyMask.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me a starting point to work from. About windows fighting each-other, I guess I'll figure out what to do about it when I come to the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a window of type _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP.

How? Well, it requires a bit of coding but the following did the trick on my system:

```
#include <X11/StringDefs.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay("");
  Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, XDefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 0, 0, WhitePixel(display, DefaultScreen(display)));

  Atom window_type = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
  Atom desktop = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP", False);
  XChangeProperty (display, win, window_type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &desktop, 1);

  XClearWindow(display, win);
  XMapWindow(display, win);

  while (1)
  {
    XEvent event;

    XNextEvent(display, &event);
  }

  XUnmapWindow(display, win);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

This showed a white window that overlapped my existing desktop but was placed below the program windows; my KDE taskbar was also still visible.

A few notes:

- You must set the property before doing XMapWindow
- The size of the window should match the size of your screen (I hardcoded my values) or you get a BadRequest error.

When I killed the program my old desktop returned, but that may not work with other window managers. Try it out.

Comment: This looks like it's probably what I need! I'll try it when I can get on tonight :)

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot! :)